# Gitlab issue when add read and write database in laravel application

Tags: laravel, gitlab, continuous-integration, cicd

I add a read and write database connection in the current laravel application, like this:

```
'mysql' => [
'read' => [
    'host' => [
        env('DB_HOST_READONLY', '127.0.0.1'),
    ],
],
'write' => [
    'host' => [
        env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
    ],
],
'sticky' => true,
'driver' => 'mysql',
'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
 ...
```

Because I have CI/CD setup on Gitlab I get this error:

```
cp .env.example .env
php artisan migrate:refresh --seed 
In Connection.php line 692:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = oauth_test and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
In Connector.php line 70:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
```

I also add in .env.example file DB_HOST_READONLY parameter which is also 127.0.0.1, the same as DB_HOST parameter. Without this change, I have this in .env.example:

```
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
```

and in database.php file:

```
'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
```

and all was woked well.
Variables in CI/CD on Gitlab are:

```
variables:
  MYSQL_USER: root
  MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
  MYSQL_DATABASE: oauth_test
  DB_HOST: mysql
```

Can you help me or have some idea?
Be free to ask if you need something more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out how it works and maybe someone uses this information and helps him also:
into .env.testing needs to change:

```
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_HOST_READONLY=127.0.0.1
```

into:

```
DB_HOST=mariadb
DB_HOST_READONLY=mariadb
```

and into gitlab-ci.yml file from this:

```
variables:
 MYSQL_USER: root
 MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "yes"
 DB_HOST: mysql
```

into this:

```
variables:
 MYSQL_USER: root
 MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "yes"
 DB_HOST: mariadb
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a database runing on `127.0.0.1` in your CI environment so it fails to run migrations.

Comment: take look at my reply to @Hatim.

Answer (score 0):

As explained by AlexD, Your Gitlab machine runs on CI env, which is another Server to build and package your application

For you tests/access to DB on you CI build , you must give the **URL** or the **ip** of the machine which host the database which can be injected in your env variable of you gitlab ci without hard coded in your .env file.

Comment: OK.I Understand. But, how that works without that, with just DB_HOST=127.0.0.1 into env file and in database.php I have 'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'). and all works?

Comment: You must change the DB_HOST and the env('DB_HOST') with the ip of the Database Host machine.  check the ip of the Mysql database , for example imagine the ip of mysql is 10.10.2.125, then in your file Db_HOST = 10.10.2.125

Comment: it's localhost or 127.0.0.1 (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/services/mysql.html)